# p:tree Navigation Error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have to display Tree structure using primefaces and based on the selection of node,need to navigate to other page.
My code is:

```
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeBean.root}"  selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}" var="node" selectionMode="single" 
            dynamic="true" cache="false">
                <p:ajax listener="#{treeBean.onDirSelected}" event="select" />
                <p:treeNode>
                    <h:outputText  value="#{node}" />
                </p:treeNode>
            </p:tree> 
        </h:form>

    </p:layoutUnit>
```

and onDirSelected method is:

```
public void onDirSelected(NodeSelectEvent event) {
        try {
            System.out.println(" here " + event.getTreeNode().getData());
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),"null", "/Damper.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error "+e.getMessage());
        } 
    }
```

I am able to print the selected node but navigation is not working.
What may be the issue??

Comment: Why is the navigation code so complicated?

Comment: And 'not working' is not smart. And how this PrimeFaces related? Does it work from a plain jsf commandButton with ajax?